# how can I handle 2 actions on a button?

Tags: java, button, javafx

I was asking myself if with java fx's button it could be possible to handle 2 clicks. Like the 1st one is calling a function then the 2nd click will stop it. For example, I have a code where a button call a Marker over a lineChart but i want to disable it with the same button when I click on one time after I activate it.

Comment: you can maintain a global flag state for the button and toggle that on clicks taking action accordingly.

Comment: @AmitD You think that I'll need a global boolean?

Comment: Yes you can use a boolean. Regarding scope of the flag, a global would work but if you can scope it down based on your usecase, that would be preferable.

Comment: I'll try it thank you. I already tried something like that 1 week ago but when I turned the boolean to false I didn't succed to turn it back to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AmitD already said, you need to maintain some kind of persistence, like a globally scoped flag.
Then, when you press the button, check the flag, execute the desired function and toggle the flag.

```
// in a scope higher than your action listener
boolean flag = false;

// code...

// action listener of your button:
if(flag){
    functionA();
} else {
    functionB();
}
flag = !flag;
```

Comment: a globally scoped flag could be a boolean ?

Comment: If your button should be a classical toggle, then yes.
If your button should have multiple states, then use an int.

Comment: I updated my answer with some code to make it easier to understand